# Django Celery Task TwythonStreamer SIGSEGV

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, twython

I had a Django project where a TwythonStreamer connection is started on a Celery task worker. The connection is started and reloaded as the search terms change. However, in it's current state and prior to updating the project to Celery 3.1.1 it would SIGSEGV when this particular tasks attempts to run. I can execute the same commands of the task in the Django Shell and have it work just fine:

```
tu = TwitterUserAccount.objects.first()
stream = NetworkStreamer(settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, tu.twitter_access_token, tu.twitter_access_token_secret)
stream.statuses.filter(track='foo,bar')
```

however, with RabbitMQ/Celery running (while in the project's virtualenv) in another window:

```
celery worker --app=project.app -B -E -l INFO
```

and try to run:

```
@task()
def test_network():
  tu = TwitterUserAccount.objects.first()
  stream = NetworkStreamer(settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, tu.twitter_access_token, tu.twitter_access_token_secret)
```

in the Django shell via:

```
test_network.apply_async()
```

the following SIGSEVG error occurs in the Celery window (upon initializing of the NetworkStreamer):

```
Task project.app.tasks.test_network with id 5a9d1689-797a-4d35-8bf3-9795e51bb0ec raised exception:
"WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)"


Task was called with args: [] kwargs: {}.

The contents of the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/foo_user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1170, in mark_as_worker_lost
human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

NetworkStreamer is simply an inherited TwythonStreamer ([as shown online here](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/streaming_api.html)).

I have other Celery tasks that run just fine in addition to various Celery Beat tasks. djcelery.setup_loader(), etc is being done. I've tried adjusting various settings (thought it might have been a pickle issue) but am not even passing any parameters. [This project structure](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) is how Celery is being setup, named, etc…

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_RESULT_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"echo": True}
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_BACKEND = 'amqp'

# Short lived sessions, disabled by default
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 18000  # 5 hours.
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
```

Versions:

- Python: 2.7.5
- RabbitMQ: 3.3.4
- Django==1.6.5
- amqp==1.4.5
- billiard==3.3.0.18
- celery==3.1.12
- django-celery==3.1.10
- flower==0.7.0
- psycopg2==2.5.3
- pytz==2014.4
- twython==3.1.2

Comment: From the [`amqp`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amqp/1.4.5) documentation: `This library should be API compatible with librabbitmq`. Make sure it is.